# PowerShell, SocketServer: How to kill SocketServer started by another program and not deleted?

Tags: sockets, powershell

I have a program that can start a socket-server using #import "ws2_32.dll"

But in debug mode and if killed the started socket server may stay alive and will block the local port e.g. 127.0.0.1:1234 in case of a re-start.

How can I kill  such 'lost' server (ports)?
I would prefer PowerShell solution but any help or idea is appreciated!

I can try to open a socket server to listen at the 'occupied' port:

```
function listen-port ($port=2019) {# 2019 is occupied - how can I 'free' it
    $endpoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([system.net.ipaddress]::any, $port)
    $listener = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
    try {
        $listener.start()
    } catch { echo $_; return }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
  ... must be used only once!
  +         $listener.start <<<< ()
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Thanks in advance,
Gooly

Comment: Grab the SysInternals utility `TCPView` and find out which process owns that port.  Given that process's PID you should be able to kill it from PowerShell using `Stop-Process <pid>`.  Once the process has been killed the OS should reclaim its resources including the allocated port.

Comment: I know the program. If I stop (kill) this, it's ok, but I have hoped there is another way without killing the program - anyway I'll count up the port until I find an open 'slot': socket = openSocket(ip,port);     hdlSocket = acceptClient( socket ); if ( socket<0 && hdlSocket<0 ) {port++;...  Not nice but working :(